# How to extract ROS parameters from bag file and save them in xlsx format?

Tags: parameters, extract, ros, bag

I have record a ROS bag file. But when I play it one terminal with

> rosbag play my_file.bag

and in the another terminal I do

> rosparam list

its only shows these

```
/rosdistro
/roslaunch/uris/host_b_lenovo_ideapad_l340_15iwl__45865
/rosversion
/run_id
```

but not the parameters I have it in my bag file. What is the problem? How can I get the parameters and extract/save them as .xlsx file?

Thanks

Comment: This may help: https://answers.ros.org/question/36716/rosparam-dump-from-launch-file/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you never actually recorded params and your bag file doesn’t contain them. `rosbag record` only records topic data and not things stored on the param sever. There isn’t currently a standard way to roll param recording into a bag file. If you want that done you’ll have to write code to do it yourself.

Comment: Can you help regarding the code? How will looks like the code?

Comment: Actually I did record the parameters. When run the launch file at the beginning of the launching the launch file  ros terminal shows the parameters.. So thats why must be in the bag file

Comment: @Macedon971 no you did not record params and that’s not how bag files work. Bag files only record topics.

Comment: ok. So how to tell bag file in simple way through command to save specific parameters while launching the file?

Comment: what if I use the rosparam dump command?

Comment: @Macedon971 you can't tell the bag file to record params; it only records topics `rosparam dump` will just output the params to stdout. If could write your own code and save/use them that way, if you wanted.

Comment: ok. find the way. Wrote a node in python the get the paremeters